# How can I configure the user profile / SAM account name in Azure AD that I got with Office 365 (or Microsoft 365 Business)?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I bought some Office 365 license and learned that I automatically got a free basic Azure AD along with that.

So now I joined my first PC to the Azure AD and logged in with an Office 365 user:

```
first.last@mydomain.com
```

but, the `%userprofile%` turned out to be:

```
C:\Users\FirstLast (C:\Users\RetoHöhener)
```

I expected:

```
C:\Users\first.last (C:\Users\reto.hoehener)
```

After some googling I found that this is the sAMAccountName (correct?).

I cannot figure out how to change the SAM account name in the Azure AD web admin application. I am missing a page that corresponds to this classical AD dialog:

[image]

`FirstLast` seems like a very inconvenient default because e.g. my last name contains a german umlaut so my userprofile would also contain a special character, which will probably break countless applications.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016155/azure-ad-and-windows-10-and-username
- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2034721-set-azure-ad-join-default-user-profile-name

Comment: What kind of Windows 95 applications can't handle Unicode in filenames and paths in 2018?

Comment: Your comment feels like a subtle put-down. Am I supposed to interpret it as "You should not worry about sAMAccountName and naming of %userprofile% in your network?

Comment: Yes. I think Microsoft has thought this through.

Comment: Whereas traditional on-premises AD might have all kind of systems and devices attached to it, having limitations that Windows doesn't, AzureAD is more lightweight. I would still avoid all possible anomalies on regular AD.

Comment: `FirstLast` looks like an anomaly to me. The user name I chose is `first.last@domain.com`, so I expected the default sAMAccountName to be the part before the `@` -> `first.last`

Comment: Has it ever been `FirstLast`? Once the folder is created it won't change its name even if `sAMAccountName` changes: the profile path is bind in the registry to the user's unique ID, instead.

Comment: Also, if a local profile is linked to a AzureAD user to preserve files and settings, the folder name might come from the original account.

Comment: No I logged on for the first time this morning with a new user and watched this userprofile being created. Also, I am very sure that I never had `FirstLast`userprofiles ever (local accounts, personal Microsoft accounts). And there is no local active directory (this is the first time I try to use AD).